# Relationship between #of cores and Dynamic Power

Tags: computer-architecture

The book I'm currently reading specifies that `Dynamic Power = (1/2) * Capacitive Load * (V^2) * frequency` However, that is assuming it's a single-core system. I wonder if we're calculating the Dynamic Power of a dual-core system, would that be twice the formula of `Dynamic Power` above ?

Comment: Perhaps you could define you terminology. I have never heard of *dynamic power* or of *capacitative load*.

Comment: The capacitive load of a dual-core system would be (roughly, ignoring, e.g., sharing parts of the memory hierarchy) twice that of a single core system (with the same core implementation), so the formula would be unchanged. (Of course, the frequency and even the voltage for different cores might be independently adjustable.) This type of question might be a better fit on the [Electrical Engineering SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/). You *might* want to flag this for migration.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Thanks! This is actually from my Computer Architecture class, so I thought I would ask it here. But you've clarified everything because the book never says anything about doubling the Capacitive Load for a dual-core system. There was just this one question that was comparing  Dynamic Power of a single-core system and Dynamic Power of a dual-core system with same `f` and `V` but the solution multiplies Dynamic Power of the dual-core system by 2. Now I understand it was because the capacitive load doubles.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton, I think you could turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The capacitive load of a dual-core system would be (roughly, ignoring, e.g., sharing parts of the memory hierarchy) twice that of a single core system (with the same core implementation), so the formula would be unchanged.

(Of course, the frequency and even the voltage for different cores might be independently adjustable.)